# Class with TryParse static method

Tags: c#

I am receiving and Expression (String) as follows:

```
String expression = "+name;-age;-city";
```

I parse this expression by splitting it using `";"` and `interpreting the +/- signs and create a List<OrderRule>`. To wrap this I created the following:

```
public class OrderExpression {

  public HashSet<OrderRule> Rules { get; set; }

  public static Boolean TryParse(String expression, out OrderExpression orderExpression) {
    // Parse expression into a List<OrderRule>
    if (_parser.ExpressionIsValid(expression)) {
       orderExpression = new OrderExpression { Rules = _parser.Parse(expression) }
       return true;
    else
       return false; 
  }
}
```

So I would use it as follows:

```
String expression = "+name;-age;-city";
OrderExpression orderExpression;
OrderExpression.TryParse(expression, out orderExpression);
```

Does this make sense? I am not sure if this architecture and naming is the way to go.

I am being picky about this because I will use it as a standard for an API to convert an order expression into a List.

Comment: better ask this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Consider that's exactly how `DateTime`'s `TryParse` works then yes I'd say it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Btw this code doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, but one thought:

```
if (_parser.ExpressionIsValid(expression)) {
   orderExpression = new OrderExpression { Rules = _parser.Parse(expression) }
```

You're checking once to make sure that it's valid, and if it is, you're actually parsing it. Could you be doing the same parsing twice?

If there's any difference between what `ExpressionIsValid` does and what `_parser.Parse` does then it's possible that `ExpressionIsValid` could return `true` but then `_parse.Parse` throws an exception. In that case, instead of returning `false` the method will throw an exception.

Since this is a `TryParse` function the intent is to make it safe - it's going to return `true` or `false` but not throw an exception if the parsing fails.

If the two methods are doing the exact same thing then perhaps you should combine them or have another function that wraps the two of them. But if they're *not* doing the same thing then you should account for the possibility that `ExpressionIsValid` returns `true` but then `Parse` throws an exception.